# Is there a Ruby Array method that returns two sub-arrays: one of specified size and another of the remaining contents?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to render the contents of the first 5 elements of an array and display "And X more" on a web page. Is there a built-in method on Array (or Enumerable) that easily separates one array into two sub-arrays: the first consisting of up to a fixed size and the second consisting of the array remainder?

I'm looking for one simple method call that will do this for me.  Most of the methods that I looked at (like `Enumerable#partition`) use a logical condition to divide the array and don't supply the index to the block.

I just wrote the following code to do what I want. Please save me from myself and direct me to a method that already does it.

```
class Array
  def bifurcate(size=length)
    if size < 0
      raise ArgumentError, "attempt to bifurcate using negative size"
    end

    remainder_size = length - size
    if remainder_size < 0
      remainder_size = 0
    end

    [
      first(size),
      last(remainder_size)
    ]
  end
end


('a'..'g').to_a.bifurcate(2)
# => [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]]
('a'..'g').to_a.bifurcate(20)
# => [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"], []]
('a'..'g').to_a.bifurcate()
# => [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"], []]
('a'..'g').to_a.bifurcate(0)
# [[], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]]
('a'..'g').to_a.bifurcate(-1)
# ArgumentError: attempt to bifurcate using negative size
```

Also, let me qualify that I want one simple method call to do what I want. Also consider that the starting array may contain duplicate values and this method needs to respect the original array and return duplicates.

Comment: What's the reason for the rollback @Wes?

Comment: To keep the question a problem that hasn't been solved.  You had updated it to reflect your solution, which makes your original question irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[array.take(3), array.drop(3)]
# [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f", "g"]]
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Was unaware of `drop`. Cool! I'm going to amend the code above to use `take` and `drop` instead of `first` and `last`.

Comment: Am glad that it helped : )

Comment: Wand Maker has given a perfect answer (according to me). So if you also feel the same, please don't forget to accept his answer.

Comment: While it isn't a single method call, I'm accepting this answer because it is the simplest and most straightforward that I've seen so far using built-in Array methods. It also seems likely that this solution is more performant than iterating over a long array with a block.

Comment: Also, I think I'll keep using my `bifurcate` monkey-patch :)

Comment: am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Enumerable#partition` along with `Enumerator#with_index` method, as shown below:

```
size = 2
(1..6).partition.with_index { |_,i| i < size }
#=> [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

---

Alternatively, if your input array can be mutated, then, following will also do the trick

```
[array.shift(size), array]
```

Comment: That's good. Didn't know about `with_index` on an `Enumerator`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
[arr[0,size_of_first], arr[size_of_first..-1] || []]
```

Comment: Yes, I know that you can slice with ranges, but your second slice could return nil without better checking.